# how to array with 2 group objects

Tags: modifiers

Im making a ring with diamond attached. I have 2 object diamond made a group and i want to array that to object in a circular manner. I have the 2 object with 2 different color and i dont want to join them and array. I want that 2 separate object to be just group and array. i have made it parent and array but only one object array not the both.  [image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately groups (even instanced) can not have an array modifier.

Your best bet will be to add the array to one object, then select the other, shift select the object with the array and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and select **Copy Modifiers**.

Make sure you use **Constant Offset** or **Object Offset** and not *Relative Offset*.

[image]

---

By request, I will add an explanation how to create the target for the array with circular symmetry

1. Snap an empty to the object, which has the array modifier: **arrayTarget**
2. Snap an empty to the center of the circle: **circlePivot**
3. Set the object *Array Offset* to: **arrayTarget**
4. Parent **arrayTarget** to **circlePivot**
5. Rotate the *circlePivot* the desired amount.

[image]

Comment: i want to know u  have selected the object offset array target what is that and how it bend and shape in to arc or circle shape. can u plz help me

Comment: I added this, to the explanation, but next time open a new question.

Comment: I believe you meant to say "groups... *cannot* have an array modifier."